# how can i convert rownames to a new column , and give it a colname?

Tags: r

data_me

```
                       TCGA-05-4244-01A-01R-1107-07 TCGA-05-4249-01A-01R-1107-07 TCGA-05-4250-01A-01R-1107-07
ENSG00000000003                         5001                         4383                         5316
                         
ENSG00000000005                          0                             0                            5
                         
ENSG00000000008                         4545                           78                           898
```

> class(data_me)
> `[1] "matrix" "array"`.
> ##data_me is not data.frame structure.

”ENSG*“are rownames now , i want to set "ENSG*" as a column and give it a colname "GENE_ID". does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data:

```
data(iris)
m <- as.matrix(iris)
rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(m)
```

Use cbind to add a new column:

```
g <- cbind(m, rownames(m))
```

Then add your new column name:

```
colnames(g) <- c(colnames(m), "GENE_ID")
```

Comment: m <- as.matrix(data_X)
> g <- cbind(m, rownames(m))
> rownames(g)
   [1] "ENSG00000000003" "ENSG00000000005" "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000457" "ENSG00000000460"

Comment: the rowname is  still ENSG ,why? i will try again ,

Comment: rownames are retained when cbinding. You can use `rownames(g) <- NULL` to remove them